# Cannot connect to Spring WebSocket server due to null Upgrade Header

Tags: java, websocket, spring-websocket, java-http-client

I created a WebSocket server using Java Spring, which worked correctly when connecting via `ws://localhost:8080/socket` and `ws://localhost:30019/socket`.  However, when I attempt to upload the socket to a host and connect to it via `ws://website.com/socket`, it cannot connect.  The difference in ports (connecting to port `80` on the host despite it running on port `30019`) is due to the host using a proxy server and redirecting port 80 of the proxy to port 30019 of the hosting server.  Connecting to the static portion of the page is the same between `localhost:30019` and `website.com`, where the webpage displays accurately in both cases.

When I try to connect, I receive a `WebSocketHandshakeException` due to a 400 response from the server:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.http.WebSocketHandshakeException
    at com.socketsimpl.Main.main(Main.java:34)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.http.WebSocketHandshakeException
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:396)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
    at  com.socketsimpl.Main.main(Main.java:27)
Caused by: java.net.http.WebSocketHandshakeException
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.resultFrom(OpeningHandshake.java:226)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1150)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:510)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:614)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:844)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:483)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:373)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1182)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1622)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:165)
Caused by: jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.CheckFailedException: Unexpected HTTP response status code 400
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.checkFailed(OpeningHandshake.java:343)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.handleResponse(OpeningHandshake.java:252)
    at java.net.http/jdk.internal.net.http.websocket.OpeningHandshake.resultFrom(OpeningHandshake.java:222)
    ... 10 more
```

When the server returns the 400 code, the error in the server console is `"Handshake failed due to invalid Upgrade header: null"`.  When switching the log level to debug by adding `logging.level.root=DEBUG` to `application.properties`, it can be seen that the `Upgrade` header is not in the headers list.

To add the header, I changed my connection code from:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
socket = client.newWebSocketBuilder()
    .buildAsync(
        URI.create("ws://website.com/socket"),
        new Listener()
    )
    .get();
```

to

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
    .header("Connection", "Upgrade")
    .header("Upgrade", "WebSocket")
    .buildAsync(
        URI.create("ws://website.com/socket"),
        new Listener()
    )
    .get();
```

However, as `Connection` and `Upgrade` are considered restricted headers by Java, this causes an `IllegalArgumentException` with description `restricted header name: "Connection"`.  As widely suggested across StackOverflow and other websites, I added the `allowRestrictedHeaders` property, making my startup command:

```
java -"Djdk.httpclient.allowRestrictedHeaders=Upgrade,Connection" -jar .\untitled-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar
```

However, the headers logged in the server console remain the exact same, the error returns to `WebSocketHandshakeException`, and the error in the server console also remains the same; it is as if I didn't add the headers.  When testing with other headers, they appear in the headers logged in the server console, meaning it is a valid way to add headers.

How can I fix the handshake, allowing the client to successfully connect to the server?

Comment: Can you use wss instead? The upgrade headers are probably stripped by the proxy.

Comment: Changing to `wss` has the same result

Comment: Note: In the server's console's listed headers, `Connection` is always listed as `close`, whether I attempt to set it or not.  `Upgrade` is never set.

Comment: I'd suggest enabling the client side logs by specifying `-Djdk.httpclient.HttpClient.log=errors,headers,requests` on the java command line on the client side. This will help you see what headers & requests are sent by the client to establish the websocket connection.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/core/java-networking.html

Comment: Another note: no need to try to specify Upgrade or Connection from the calling code. There is a reason why they are restricted: the HttpClient will set them appropriately.

Comment: @daniel This shows that the `Connection` and `Upgrade` headers are indeed added, being set to `Upgrade` and `websocket` respectively.  However, on the server, `Connection` is still `close` and there is still no `Upgrade` header

Comment: If it doesn't work: blame the proxy ;-) I believe the issue is with the proxy you are using - or the proxy that sits in front of the server - if any. Fix the proxy.

Comment: As you said, it was an issue with the proxy.  It wasn't forwarding headers, so I contacted the host and they fixed it.  Thanks!